# Replace char(0x10) with a String (The Optimized way)

Tags: c#, string, performance

This is a common question but I hope this does not get tagged as a duplicate since the nature of the question is different (please read the whole not only the title)

Unaware of the existence of `String.Replace` I wrote the following:

```
int theIndex = 0;

while ((theIndex = message.IndexOf(separationChar, theIndex)) != -1) //we found the character
{
    theIndex++;
    if (theIndex < message.Length)//not in the last position 
    {
        message = message.Insert(theIndex, theTime);
    }
    else 
    {
        // I dont' think this is really neccessary
        break;
    }

} //while finding characters
```

As you can see I am replacing occurrences of separationChar in the message String with a String called "theTime".

Now, this works ok for small strings but I have been given a really huge String (in the order of several hundred Kbytes- by the way is there a limit for String or StringBuilder??) and it takes a lot of time...

So my questions are:

1) Is it more efficient if I just do

```
oldString=separationChar.ToString();
newString=oldString.Insert(theTime);

message= message.Replace(oldString,newString);
```

2) Is there any other way I can process very long Strings to insert a String (theTime) when finding some char *in a very fast and efficient way??*

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` it's a mutable class so every operation doesn't have to instantiate a new string you just modify it.

Comment: Do you think that will have an impact on speed?

Comment: If your dealing with large enough strings that you have performance issues I would expect it to help yes.

Comment: I need to take that back, string builder is great for appending but you want to insert. The problem is that StringBuilder is implemented with arrays so unless you just overwrite chars without changing the length it wont improve performance. You want a Linked List implementation, try `LinkedList<char>`. The other thing you can try is doing a `split` on the original string using `separationChar` and then `join` using `theTime`. That way you only need to go through the string once making your O(n^2) problem into a O(n) problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Danny already mentioned, `string.Insert()` actually creates a *new* instance each time you use it, and these also have to be garbage collected at some point.

You could instead start with an empty `StringBuilder` to construct the result string:

```
public static string Replace(this string str, char find, string replacement)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.Length); // initial capacity
    int pointer = 0;
    int index;
    while ((index = str.IndexOf(find, pointer)) >= 0)
    {
        // Append the unprocessed data up to the character
        result.Append(str, pointer, index - pointer);
        // Append the replacement string
        result.Append(replacement);
        // Next unprocessed data starts after the character
        pointer = index + 1;
    }

    // Append the remainder of the unprocessed data
    result.Append(str, pointer, str.Length - pointer);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

This will not cause a new `string` to be created (and garbage collected) for each occurrence of the character. Instead, when the internal buffer of the `StringBuilder` is full, it will create a new buffer chunk "of sufficient capacity". Quote from [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,bb3473794f7408f5), when its buffer is full:

> Compute the length of the new block we need
>
> We make the new chunk at least big enough for the current need (minBlockCharCount), but also as big as the current length (thus doubling capacity), up to a maximum
>   (so we stay in the small object heap, and never allocate really big chunks even if
>   the string gets really big).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question.
I am writing an answer because I have to report that I tried the solution in my question 1) and it is indeed more efficient according to the results of my program. String.Replace can replace a string(from a char) with another string very fast.

```
oldString=separationChar.ToString();
newString=oldString.Insert(theTime);

message= message.Replace(oldString,newString);
```